# Sending photo in Facebook chat

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an app in which I can chat with my Facebook friends.
[image]

Now I want to send a photo to my friend in chat just like the Facebook iOS app
[image]

How can I do this??

Thanks.

Comment: I have done the text chat part .. I don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now [public Facebook Chat API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) doesn't support files attachments.

But, you can implement it yourself, for example follow this way:

1. Upload image you want to send to any public server. For example look at [QuickBlox Content code sample](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-content-ios) . You can upload image to it server and get public url. It's free.
2. Send to opponent link to this image
3. Opponent just show this image using link

thats all, hope this help